Use MQTT to send telemetry message to Azure IOT hub
How can I send telemetry message to Azure IOT hub using swift. I have python code, I am very new to swift.
I am trying to use code from here
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
import ssl

path_to_root_cert = "<local path to digicert.cer file>"
device_id = "<device id from device registry>"
sas_token = "<generated SAS token>"
iot_hub_name = "<iot hub name>"
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Device connected with result code: " + str(rc))
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    print("Device disconnected with result code: " + str(rc))
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("Device sent message")
client = mqtt.Client(client_id=device_id, protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.username_pw_set(username=iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net/" +
                       device_id + "/?api-version=2021-04-12", password=sas_token)
client.tls_set(ca_certs=path_to_root_cert, certfile=None, keyfile=None,
               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, ciphers=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(False)
client.connect(iot_hub_name+".azure-devices.net", port=8883)
client.publish("devices/" + device_id + "/messages/events/", '{"id":123}', qos=1)
client.loop_forever()


you have to install third party library named CocoaMQTT
and setup the server same as you did in python
then in app delegate file you have to call this delegate method CocoaMQTT5Delegate
setup socket when app become active
for more information you can check example of the library on GitHub
or you can comment your email I can share the full code personally

The Swift code below is for using MQTT to send telemetry messages to Azure IoT Hub.
I referred to this Microsoft documentation, and I would like to thank @Kelly Gremban for the GitHub link from which I referred to the code.
The code below uses the MQTT protocol for communication with Azure IoT Hub.
    
    private let connectionString = "<Your IoT Hub Connection String>"
    
    private let iotProtocol: IOTHUB_CLIENT_TRANSPORT_PROVIDER = MQTT_Protocol

    private var iotHubClientHandle: IOTHUB_CLIENT_LL_HANDLE!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        iotHubClientHandle = IoTHubClient_LL_CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, iotProtocol)
        if (iotHubClientHandle == nil) {
            print("Failed to create IoT handle")
            return
        }
     
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(sendTelemetry), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func sendTelemetry() {
        let temperature = String(format: "%.2f", drand48() * 15 + 20)
        let humidity = String(format: "%.2f", drand48() * 20 + 60)
        
        let telemetryData: [String: String] = ["temperature": temperature, "humidity": humidity]
        let messageString = telemetryData.description
 
        let messageHandle: IOTHUB_MESSAGE_HANDLE = IoTHubMessage_CreateFromByteArray(messageString, messageString.utf8.count)
        
        if messageHandle != OpaquePointer.init(bitPattern: 0) {
 IoTHubClient_LL_SendEventAsync(iotHubClientHandle, messageHandle, { result, userContext in
                if result == IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONFIRMATION_OK {
                    print("Message sent successfully")
                } else {
                    print("Failed to send message")
                }
            }, nil)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
  
        if let clientHandle = iotHubClientHandle {
            IoTHubClient_LL_Destroy(clientHandle)
        }
    }




Output:


Hi Thank you for response. It seems good, but I need code most probably with CocoaMqtt because in part of DPS, certificate base provisioning in not available in any iOS SDK, so I am approaching whole DPS process with REST API approach.
